# finding an image of a linear transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

I am so confused in how its asking of finding an image of infinity. I am in my complex class and we have a test and this was part of the past midterm, I feel like if I do one all of the other ones should be the same I assume. Please give me some hints in how to solve it. Thank you

For the following fractional linear transformations, find the image of $\infty$.

a) $\displaystyle \frac{1}{z+3}$

b) $\displaystyle \frac{2z-1}{z+i}$

c) $\displaystyle \frac{2z-i}{iz+i}$

d) $\displaystyle \frac{2z-5}{i-3}$

Thank you so much

Comment: You can treat this as a limit; i.e. evaluate the limit as $z \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: so would the image be 0, 2, -2i, none ??? thats if i compute it as $ z \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: d) is $\infty$, you got the others right.

Answer (score 2):

Hint, if $a$ is a finite, non null complex number: 
$$a / \infty = 0$$
$$a \cdot \infty = \infty$$
$$a + \infty = \infty$$
$$- \infty = \infty$$
For cases like $\frac{a \cdot z + b}{c \cdot z + d}$, where $a$ and $c$ are not null, you can take the limit, and it's $a/c$.

Comment: but i dont get it. When I took the limit as z approaches infinity. I just used the horizantal asymptote rule and came with that connclusion. How would I actually try solving it using complex rules

Comment: Simply divide numerator and denominator by $z$. Since it tends toward $\infty$, you can assume $z$ is not null and division is legal. Then the $b/z$ and $d/z$ terms both tend toward zero, and it's easy to conclude. You can apply this to other polynomials as well, as long as denominator and numerator have same degree. Otherwise, the limit will be $0$ or $\infty$ according to degree difference.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to look at this is to write down the inverse transformation:
$\frac{dz-b}{-cz+a}$ which is equal to $\infty$ when $z=a/c$.